# Como realizar testes em métodos privados utilizando Mockito

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade, tdd, mock, mockito

este final de semana dei uma lida sobre o `Mockito` e testes dublês, e me surgiu a seguinte ideia. Testar métodos privados com este framework.

Vi que o `PowerMock` realiza tal procedimento, mas alguém já tentou fazer isso utilizando o `Mockito` com `reflection`?

Nessa discussão gostaria também de saber dos amigos a opinião sobre testar ou não métodos privados, vi algumas discussões sobre isso no `SO.com` e fiquei em dúvida, pois quando eu declaro um método privado apenas segmento para cada uma método uma responsabilidade e não colocar varias coisas em um mesmo método.

Obrigado

Comment: Acredito que não seja necessário testar métodos privados, pois eles existem como auxilio aos públicos. Testar os métodos públicos deve ser suficiente.

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente não é possível com o Mockito, mas existe o PowerMock, um framework que estende outros frameworks como o Mockito, e permite [testar métodos privados](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate).

Entretanto, em geral, se um método privado possui alguma lógica ou algoritmo suficientemente complexos para precisarem de um testes unitário por si só, então talvez seja conselhável delegar a responsabilidade a outra classe e então testá-la.

Outra possibilidade, que sacrifica um pouco o *design*, seria tornar o método "protegido" (`protected`) de forma que outras classes no mesmo pacote consigam acessá-lo. Se houver divisão adequada de pacotes no sistema isso geralmente não é um problema. Então basta criar o teste no mesmo pacote.

Na verdade, muitas vezes o nível de visibilidade `private` acaba sendo "forte" demais. Já vi muitos casos onde precisei estender uma classe e um método importante era privado, obrigando-me a criar outra classe ou duplicar o método.